# How can I normalize a value before I validate it in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, normalization

I have a rule like this:

```
'email' => 'required|email|unique',
```

But say I want to consider `johnsmith+something@example.org` as equivalent to `johnsmith@example.org`, for example. Is there a way to normalize an input value before I validate it?

I have thought about using middleware for this, in the style of `TrimStrings`, but I would only want to change non-empty values on a very selective basis, so the middleware approach would be casting too wide a net.

Comment: I think middleware is an ok option.  You also could write a custom validator as well. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: @jgetner It is more applicable to some [global] helper function because it's functionality is wider than just some kind of request guard: i.e. you could normalize™ data in any other place in code where needed `function normalizeEmail ($a = 'johnsmith+something@example.org') { return $a; }`. <- just a pseudo, still need logic inside. custom helper or class with static methods autoloaded through composer would do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there isn't a way to modify a request attribute's value as it moves through validation rules. Having given it some more thought, I think that's probably for the best. It'd mean so-called "validation rules" that violate the SRP, and also the side-effects would likely be a huge source of bugs.

I've realised though that the real problem here is wanting to wrap some normalisation logic around the `unique` rule.

As far as I can tell this is only possible using a [validation extension](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#using-extensions), as this is the only approach where your validation method receives an instance of the `Validator` object. With that object available, you can then normalize the value before using the `Validator` to apply the `unique` rule:

```
<?php

namespace App\Validators;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class UniqueEmail
{
    public function validate($attribute, $value, $parameters, Validator $validator)
    {
        $value = $this->normalize($value);

        return $validator->validateUnique($attribute, $value, $parameters);
    }

    protected function normalize($value)
    {
        // ...

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Register the extension in the `AppServiceProvider`'s `boot` method:

```
Validator::extend('unique_email', 'App\Validators\UniqueEmail@validate');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `rule` class like following

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class EmailValidation implements Rule
{
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
         //Perform logic on $value
         return trim($value) === $value;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This didn't actually solve my issue, but did help me to think about the problem in a different way. I didn't want an entirely custom rule, but I did want to customise the way `unique` works. Unfortunately, that can't be done with a `Rule` class, but can be done with an extension. I'm reasonably satisfied with the solution I've come up with now - have posted it as an answer if you're curious.